# How to do pagination for photos on Facebook graph data using Android-SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I want to get all the photos in my profile. I want to use pagination as a query at a time returns a few results. My response has  'after' and 'before' tags. Even when I use the after parameter in my query I keep getting the same results back, no new data gets added. How should I modify my query so that I get the next set of results?

My query -

```
do {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "photos{source}");
            parameters.putString("after", afterString[0]);
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.i("GetPhotoUrlTask", response.toString());
                            parsePhotoUrls(response);
                        }
                    });
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAndWait();
        } while (!noData[0] == true);
```

My response -

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"965494620","photos":{"data":[{"id":"47832732","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=4783552732&set=a.411783262.126046.10&type=1"},
...
...
...
"paging":{"cursors":{"after":"TVRBNE16UTJOREl5TlRVeE1UQXdPakV5TnpnMU1ETTVPVGM2TXprME1EZAzVOalF3TmpRM09ETTIZD","before":"TkRjNE16STNNekkxTlRVek1EQTJPakV6TlRVMk1UQXhNekk2TXprME1EZAzVOalF3TmpRM09ETTIZD"}}}}, error: null}
```

How should I modify my query so that I get the next set of results?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging

You should be able to get the next results with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=photos{source}&after={after_token}
```

where `{after_token}` is the token coming from the last request, in your example `TVRBNE16UTJOREl5TlRVeE1UQXdPakV5TnpnMU1ETTVPVGM2TXprME1EZAzVOalF3TmpRM09ETTIZD`

Comment: Query 1:- Response: After1

Query2&after={after1}:-  Response: After2

Query3&after={after2}:- Response: After1

Why am I getting back the same value for after param in query 3?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: The value of the after parameter in the response is alternating, which means i am getting 2 sets of data repeatedly, but not all the data